# Filter by country

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-php-sdk

I want get all regions for a country from my Google Analytics account. I wrote the below code to get all regions:

```
$metrics = 'ga:visits';
$dimensions = 'ga:country=$iso,ga:region,ga:regionId';

$ga = $this->getGa();
$gaResponse = $ga->data_ga->get('ga:122752178', $start, $end, $metrics, ['dimensions' => $dimensions]);
$resultset = $gaResponse->getRows();
```

So, how i can get all regions for a country ? For example, Argentina (AR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a suggestion: Try your query out in the [query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

### Answer: Use the `filters` parameter.

Filter by [`ga:country==Argentina`](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-12-30&end-date=2016-01-06&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3Acountry%2Cga%3Aregion&sort=-ga%3Asessions&filters=ga%3Acountry%3D%3DArgentina).

```
$metrics = 'ga:sessions';

$optParams = array(
  'dimensions' => 'ga:country,ga:region,ga:regionId',
  'sort' => '-ga:sessions',
  'filters' => 'ga:country==Argentina',
  'max-results' => '25');

$ga = $this->getGa();
$gaResponse = $ga->data_ga->get(
    $ids,
    $start,
    $end,
    $metrics,
    $optParams);
$resultset = $gaResponse->getRows();
```

This will get you a list of all the regions from which you had sessions, not an extensive list of regions within a country.

Also `ga:visists` is deprecated, you should use `ga:sessions`, see the [Core Reporting API Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) and [Dimensions and Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

Comment: Excellent !! Thank you :)